# Querying MSSQL using pyodbc putting results in one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in mssql with columns of data. I can successfully connect and pull data but when I'm pulling the data its getting put in one column of the dataframe. What am I missing?

I've tried the below code with is putting all the results into one column of the data frame.

```
 import pyodbc
 import pandas as pd


 conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=server;'
                  'Database=server;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT [leadid], [CreateDate], [Status Change Count], 
[logdate], [statustitle], [groupedstatus], [leadbucket] FROM vel_actions""")
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

df.head() returns:

```
0 [2065004, 2018-03-12 03:06:10.0000000, 1, 2018...
1  [2065004, 2018-03-12 03:06:10.0000000, 2, 2018...
2  [2065004, 2018-03-12 03:06:10.0000000, 3, 2018...
3  [2065004, 2018-03-12 03:06:10.0000000, 4, 2018...
4  [2065004, 2018-03-12 03:06:10.0000000, 5, 2018...
```

How do I get the data into a dataframe and keep the columns that my sql table is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of tuples.  Within, will not be found the data for naming columns.

`sqlite3` is substituted for `pyodbc` because `pyodbc` does not enable a demonstrative example.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty_real, price_real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select date, trans, symbol, qty_real, price_real from stocks")
list_o_tuples = c.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(list_o_tuples)
df.columns = ["date", "trans", "symbol", "qty_real", "price_real"]
print(df)
```

For sqlite3, you can have it return the column names, which may be passed into your `DataFrame` constructor.

```
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select date, trans, symbol, qty_real, price_real from stocks")
list_o_dict_like_rows = c.fetchall()
l = [dict(i) for i in list_o_dict_like_rows]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df)

conn.close()
```

And for `pyodbc` the answer (cannot be reproduced here) would be something like:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT [leadid], [CreateDate], [Status Change Count], 
[logdate], [statustitle], [groupedstatus], [leadbucket] FROM vel_actions""")
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=columns)
```